# How to use aspell with neovim?

Tags: neovim, aspell

I would prefer to use aspell rather than neovim's built in spell checker. I can use aspell from the zsh command line, and also with 'regular' vim, but when I use

`:!aspell check %`

inside neovim, it gives the error message: `Error: stdin is not a terminal.`  (Instead of displaying a standard aspell correction environment).

I'm at a loss as to what else to try.  The error message actually has a lot of garbage characters before it.  Things like: '^[[?1049h^[[1;24r^[(B^[['  and also ends with 'shell returned 255'.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm glad I could help, 1++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
 :term set modifiable ; aspell check %
```

When the new screen opens, you need to do an 'i' for insert mode, then the aspell correction environment is correct and usable.  When it exits, pressing 'Enter' is required to get back to the original file.

I (Leonard) rewrote Freeman's reply completely. His initial reply didn't work, but dialog in the comments led to this solution, and I want to award him the bonus, but have it associated with the right info.  Thx [@Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252518/freeman)

Comment: @Leonard It's possible that the issue you're experiencing is related to the configuration of your Neovim environment or the version of `Aspell` that you're using, if you want let me know explain it more for you!

Comment: [@freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252518/freeman)  Yes please.  When I do a aspell -v I get the following version info: @(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)

Comment: It's normal because Aspell is built on the Ispell codebase, so it inherits some of Ispell's versioning information.

Comment: [@freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252518/freeman).  And do you have any thoughts about if a different versions might work better?

Comment: @Leonard i think you can open a new split window with the terminal emulator using the command:`:term aspell check %`,it maybe will open a new split window at the bottom of the screen,where you can see the output of the aspell command then you can interact with the aspell correction environment as usual.